# Почему под стек в ассемблере выделяется именно 256 байт?

Tags: ассемблер

Вопрос от преподавателя: почему мы выделяем именно 256 байт под стек?

```
text    segment            ;(1)Начало сегмента команд 
assume  CS:text,DS:data    ;(2)Сегментный регистр CS будет указывать на сегмент 
               ;команд, а сегментный регистр DS - на сегмент данных 
begin:  mov AX,data        ;(4)Адрес сегмента данных сначала загрузим в АХ, 
    mov DS,AX          ;(5)а затем перенесем из АХ в DS 
    mov AH,09h         ;(6)Функция DOS 9h вывода на экран 
    mov DX,offset mesg ;(7)Адрес выводимого сообщения должен быть в DX 
    int 21h            ;(8)Вызов DOS 
    mov AH,4Ch         ;(9)Функция 4Ch завершения программы 
    mov AL, 0          ;(10)Код 0 успешного завершения 
    int 21h            ;(11)Вызов DOS 
text    ends               ;(12)Конец сегмента команд 
data    segment            ;(13)Начало сегмента данных 
mesg    db 'Привет!', 10, 13, '$' ;(14)Выводимый текст
data    ends               ;(15)Конец сегмента данных 
stk     segment stack      ;(16)Начало сегмента стека 
        db 256 dup (0)     ;(17)Резервируем 256 байт для стека 
stk     ends               ;(18)Конец сегмента стека 
        end begin          ;(19)Конец текста программы с точкой входа begin
```

Comment: Во первых, это красиво, а во вторых, 256 байт хватит всем

Comment: А какой то более теоретический ответ можно найти? Не скажу же я ему, что это просто красиво)

Comment: Без разницы сколько, главное чтобы кратно размеру слова в системе (2 байта в 16 битной, 4 в 32-битной, 8 - в 64 битной), и хватило под конкретную задачу. Может вообще не быть стека. Для вызова исключений требуется стек, чтобы сохранить содержимое всех регистров и адреса возврата, поэтому без стека совсем в данном случае не получится обойтись. Вроде бы можно меньше 256 байт, но нужно уточнять (сколько конкретно байт сохраняется при вызове исключения). 256 в целом достаточно красивое число)

Comment: Я об этом и писал. Просто 256 правильное круглое число. Можно и 1024 взять.

Comment: А он тут вообще используется?...

Comment: Я бы перед стеком еще какую-нибудь директиву выравнивания вставил (`.align 16 // на 16 байт` или что этот ассемблер понимает?)